# Group theory: am I allowed to "multiply" both sides of an equation with the same element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First of all, I'm not a mathematican in any sense, I'm just curiuous sometimes. So please forgive me for not being rigorous in stating my actual problem.

Given a (non-abelian) group with its usual axioms, consisting of the set $G$
 (lets call the group also $G$) and an operation $\cdot$, do I have to proof that from
$$h\cdot g=e$$ follows that
$$(h\cdot g)\cdot g^{-1}=e\cdot g^{-1}$$ ,
where $h,g \in G$ and $g^{-1}$ is the inverse element of $g$ and $e$ is the neutral element?

In principle this question is very similar to

[Algebra: What allows us to do the same thing to both sides of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805937/algebra-what-allows-us-to-do-the-same-thing-to-both-sides-of-an-equation)

but if I got it right, a group doesn't need to be composed of "numbers". It can be anything, such as a rotation maybe or a far more abstract object I can't even imagine

So basically my question is, if the answer to the related question applies to any group in general or if I have to prove this somehow?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english- and math-skills.

Comment: Yes, it works also for "non numbers" (as per many similar question linked to the linked question); it is enough that the *operation* is defined between the objects you are dealing with, and it is always true that : "if $a=b$, then $(a \text { op } c = b \text { op } c)$. See [rules for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Comment: Yes! The inverse in a group is unique! Assume $x^{-1}=a^{-1}$. The definition of the inverse gives us $x^{-1} x = e$ and if  $x^{-1}=a^{-1}$ that is equivalent to $xa^{-1} =e$ and multiplying with $a$ gives $x=a$.

Comment: Doesn't even need to be a group.  Applies to everything.  If $a$ and $b$ are two names for the same thing, and "$manipulate()$" is a manipulation that has a consistent result determined by its input then $manipulate(a)=manipulate(b)$... Admittedly abstract mathematics can into great detail as to how we can *define*,interpret, and prove such simple concepts of say "a thing is itself" but that's fairly advanced and abstract.

Comment: @cptflint although that is what the op was eventually trying to show, his/her question was much more basic. S/he was asking how we can multiply both sides by $a$ and if that is something that needs to be prove.  If $M=N$ then do we know $Ma=Na$.

Comment: @fleablood Mhhh, sure? If $g^{-1}$ isn't unique, that result won't be true. $g^{-1}$ ist just an element of the group which satisfies $g^{-1} g= e$. If you don't know, that this is a unique element, you can not interpret the multiplication of $g^{-1}$ with other elements than $g$. Or am I missing something here? 

I think the uniqueness is necessary for that.

Comment: Subtle side issue: To say: if $a=b$ then $manipulate(a)=manipulate(b)$ requires that "$manipulate()$" is well-defined and consistent. I think some confusion comes from things such as.  If $a=b$ then $a^2=b^2$ and $a*0 =b^2$ is true. But if $a^2=b^2$ or $a*0=b*0$ then we *can't* say $a=b$.  But this is because $manipulate$ means "square it" or "multiply" by zero, is well defined and consistent. The concept of "find a number that when squared is equal to the input" or "find a number that when multiplied by zero is the input" are *NOT* well-defined and are inconsistent.

Comment: That's what I am talking about. The multiplication by $g^{-1}$ is only well defined because of its uniqueness. 

Thx for your clarification!

Comment: @cptflint.  If $g^{-1}$ isn't unique then referring to something as "$g^{-1}$" doesn't make sense.  If you have $M$ is something $N=M$ and $a$ is something you will always have $Ma = Na$. and if $M$ is $h\cdot g$ (whatever that is) and $h\cdot g = e$ (whatever that is) and $g^{-1}$ is something (whatever it is) you will have $(h\cdot g)\cdot g^{-1}=e\cdot g^{-1}$.

Comment: In a *group* you have the "division" property:  If $ac = bc$ then $a=b$.  But i)you have to *prove* this by proving that "divide by $c$" is a consistent manipulation in a group (The proof is, by axiom/definition every $c$ has $c^{-1}$ and the operation $\cdot$ is a binary operation and the result follows) and ii) in other mathematical constructs this is *not* a consistent manipulation.  For example in "clock" arithmetic where we return to $0$ every time we get to $12$.  We have $4*2=8$ and $4*5=8$ (because in counting to $20$ we go back to $0$ at $12$) but $2\not=5$. "divide by 4" not defined!

Comment: Okay, call it $i(g)$. When defining a group you need to force that there is at least one element $i(g)$ which satisfies $e=i(g)*g$. The uniqueness is just a consequence of that! And multiplying that with another element is only well defined when it is a unique element. And if you understand that, what you said is the next step and the answer to the given problem. But I agree: Uniqueness can be assumed when writing $g^{-1}$. That was my fault :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have, say,
$$a=b$$
then for any function $f$, any function at all, we have
$$f(a)=f(b)$$
For two values that are the same, inputting them into $f$ will give you the same output, because $f$, being a function, evaluates to a unique value on a given input. Multiplying by $g^{-1}$ on the right is a function. Calling this function $m_g$, we have
$$m_g(x) = x\cdot g^{-1}$$
For your equation, we are saying that
$$h\cdot g = e$$
so
$$(h\cdot g)\cdot g^{-1} = m_g(h\cdot g) = m_g(e) = e\cdot g^{-1}$$
Therefore the manipulation is valid.