# How to know that we have found the correct solution set of an inequality? AND why is "my method" not working?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Background:** I was solving this inequality: $(1-4x)^{-1}\geq 7$.

I did it as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\quad(1-4 x)^{-1} \geq 7 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-4 x} \geq 7 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{7} \geq 1-4 x \\ 
\quad\left[\begin{array}{l}
1-4 x \neq 0 \text { and is  positive as if }\\
 \frac{a}{b}>0 
\text { and } a>0 \Rightarrow b>0.\\
\text {Hence I can multiply} \text{the sides with 1-4x,}\\
\text{without reversing sign. }
\end{array}\right] \\
\Rightarrow \frac{-6}{7} \geq-4 x \\
\Rightarrow x \geq\frac{6}{28} \\
\Rightarrow x \geq\frac{3}{14} \\
\therefore \text { Soln set }=\left[\frac{3}{14}, \infty\right)
\end{array}
$$

But this is not the answer; the answer is:
$
\left\{x \mid \frac{3}{14} \leq x<\frac{1}{4}\right\} \text { or }\left[\frac{3}{14}, \frac{1}{4}\right)
$

After thinking some time I realised that the other end point can be found if we solve the question as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{1-4 x} \geq 7 \\
\Rightarrow & 1-4x>0 \quad[\text { The reason is same }] \\
\Rightarrow & x<\frac{1}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question:** This post has two main questions:

**First question:** I know that the maximum number of roots an equation, in one variable of any degree, can have, will be same as its degree.
**So for the inequalties, how could I be sure that I have found all the end point(s)?** In some question the solution set is union of other two disjoint sets, So in this cases how could I be sure that I have found all the disjoint sets?
For this specific question, how could I be sure that this is finally the solution set? Can't it be that the author(of the book the problem is from) missed considering other inequalities, like me, which could have given us another set(s), so finally the answer would be union of those sets?

So I can sum up the above question in this question: How to know that we have found the correct solution set of an inequality?

**Second question:** Adding, subtracting and multiply(by non-zero number/polynomial) both side by same number/polynomial always led us to equivalent equation and inequality. In this case I multiplied by $1-4x$, which I know for sure is not zero. So according to the logic I must get an equivalent inequality i.e. the solution set of the new inequality must be same as that of the original inequality, but apparently this is not the case with this question i.e. solution set of $(1-4x)^{-1}\geq 7$ is not same as that of $\frac{1}{1-4x}\geq 7$. Why? I can get the correct answer by solving as others have mentioned in the answer, but, the second question is, why is "my method" not working?

Comment: From $-6/7\geq -4x$ you deduce $x\leq 6/28$. This is an error; you forgot to flip the sign (because you divided by a negative number). The correct deduction is $x\color{red}{\geq} 6/28$. Together with the fact that $1-4x>0$ (meaning $x<1/4$), this yields the correct solution.

Comment: One further point. The reason your first approach doesn’t generate the solution set is that your logic only works in the forward direction: you’ve shown that *if* $x$ satisfies the first inequality in that chain of reasoning, *then* $x$ satisfies the last inequality in the chain of reasoning. **But** the converse might not be true! I.e., the steps might not be reversible; at the end you might generate a solution set that is too large. The step where reversibility breaks down is $1/7\geq 1-4x$. This is a correct deduction *from* $(1-4x)^{-1}\geq 7$, but the two inequalities aren’t *equivalent*.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I fixed the error.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I think youre right, but can you please refer me something on this topic?

Comment: The answer to your larger question is in my other comment. What you’re missing is that one inequality can *follow from* another without the inequalities being *equivalent* (in the sense of having the same solution set), that is, without the reverse being true. Here’s a similar example dealing with equations rather than inequalities: from $x=2$ it *follows that* $x^2=4$, but these equations are not equivalent. The reason is that $x=2$ does not in turn follow from $x^2=4$. When we manipulate equations or inequalities by “doing the same thing to both sides,” we have to think about reversibility.

Comment: You asked for a reference. You can read my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805937/algebra-what-allows-us-to-do-the-same-thing-to-both-sides-of-an-equation/805939#805939

Comment: @symplectomorphic I agree with you that not all same operations on both sides lead you to equivalent equations/inequality. But  is there any error in assuming that "Adding, subtracting and multiply(by non-zero number/polynomial) both side by same number/polynomial always led us to equivalent equation and inequality"?

Comment: Yes, there is an error in that assumption, as your own example illustrates. Multiplying $(1-4x)^{-1}\geq 7$ by the polynomial $1-4x$ on both sides does not generate an equivalent inequality.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Now I have this question: Is there any method which will tell us if the operation will led us to equivalent inequality/equations or not? There might be no such method. But in the case of squaring both sides **of an equation**, we check the solutions we get after solving the *new* equation, by putting them in the *original* equation. But we cant use this trick for inequalities; we will have to check infinite solutions. So is this correct t  conclude that *"If you want to solve an inequality, then don't multiply by non-constant polynomials"*?

Comment: This discussion is getting too long for comments, but you’re asking good questions. Multiplying by a polynomial is fine (that is, can lead to an equivalent problem) so long as you preserve all relevant conditions. In your case the equivalent statements are “$(1-4x)^{-1}\geq 7$” and the logical conjunction “$1\geq7(1-4x)$ *and* $(1-4x)>0$.” You forgot to preserve the positivity assumption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126284/discussion-between-hiterdean-and-symplectomorphic).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the correct answer is right here in your calculations:

$$ \frac{1}{7} \geq 1-4 x \quad\left[\begin{array}{l}
1-4 x \neq 0 \text { and is  positive as if }\\
 \frac{a}{b}>0 
\text { and } a>0 \Rightarrow b>0.\\
\text {Hence I can multiply} \text{the sides with 1-4x,}\\
\text{without reversing sign. }
\end{array}\right]$$

Specifically, it's this excerpt from the first line in the brackets:

> $1-4 x \neq 0$  and is  positive ...

The $\neq 0$ part is redundant actually; all you really need is the part
that says it "is positive".
In short, you have shown that $$1-4 x  > 0. \tag1$$

The part on the left side of the brackets also is correct, of course:
$$ \frac17 \geq 1-4 x. \tag2 $$

From Inequation $(1)$ you get $$x < \frac14,$$
and from Inequation $(2)$ you get $$x \geq \frac3{14}.$$

Your error was that after proving $1-4 x  > 0$ you ignored that fact in the final solution set.

Answer (score 0):

For inequalities when you multiply with a number you need first to verify it is not negative because if it then the direction will be flipped!

The approach to solve such a problem is move all terms to one side then you will have either $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$ so you need to study the sign of the function and to do so you need to find it is zeros and point of discontinuities

Comment: I multiplied the inequality with $1-4x$, as I am sure that it is a non-negative number. The reason is given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply by $1-4x$, we are still not sure if we could have introduced additional solutions, implicitly, you have assume that $1-4x > 0$ and it should be incorporated to the solution directly and you should note it down and take intersection at the end.

What I do usually is rather than multiplying $1-4x$, I multiply by $(1-4x)^2$  and note that $x \ne \frac14$.

$$\frac1{1-4x} \ge 7, x\ne \frac14$$

$$1-4x\ge 7(1-4x)^2, x\ne \frac14$$

$$(1-4x)(7-28x-1) \le 0, x\ne \frac14$$

$$(1-4x)(6-28x) \le 0, x\ne \frac14$$

$$(1-4x)(3-14x) \le 0, x\ne \frac14$$

$$\frac3{14} \le x < \frac14$$

Once you convert a fractional inequality to polynomial form, you can sketch the region.

Edit:

Note that $(1-4x)^{-1}=\frac1{1-4x}$. You have to take intersection of the condition that you imposed.

Comment: @Siong_Thye_Goh I have modified the question, have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure of not missing any solution sets, you can do the calculations as follow:

$$\frac1{1-4x}\ge7\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac1{1-4x}-7\ge0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{1-7+28x}{1-4x}\ge0$$

We have $\dfrac{28x-6}{1-4x}\ge0$, hence $\frac3{14}\le x<\frac14$.